# disabled job still runs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, jobs

In SQL Server 2014 (currently 12.0.6205) when I disable backup jobs either manually through SSMS or through T-SQL, I am seeing that the job still runs regardless of the job's enable status. Do I need to also always disable a job's schedule as well? That seems wrong.

- These jobs are backup jobs using maintenance plans
- They weren't running when they were disabled

Comment: Were the job running when you disable it?

Comment: stop the job and then disable it.

Comment: You may have another process that is calling the job by executing sp_start_job.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: IIRC you do need to disable the schedule.